# Navigation between screens

Tags: react-native, navigation, screen, tabnavigator

I would like to retrieve the information related to my `Tab.navigator` (the active one, the one I am on at the moment X. )
Someone could explain me how can I do that. I tried a lot of thing to receive these informations like `route.name` but nothing works.

I hope you understand what I want to say and thanks you in advance guys.
If you need some code or something like that I will be here to give you this.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? For what you need route.name?

Comment: basically I want to get the name of my Tab.Screen in order to know where I am because I want to navigate in a page through 2 different Tab.Screen